# how can I configure onedrive to save every new file in a folder

Tags: onedrive

I'd like onedrive to store every new file created or saved in a folder of my choice. That is to save it without any intervention from me even if a particular filename does not already exist. I know that existing files will sync by themselves but I want new files to be saved to onedrive as well.

Comment: You have to create the folder then save the file in that folder, outside of that, what you want isn't realistic

Comment: I usually save a significant number of files in various folders (sometimes new folders) inside the parent folder and it's not easy to remember every single file. Syncing is supposed to solve such problems... I don't understand why you believe that this is not realistic.

Comment: You want OneDrive to create folders for you, but it does not have that feature, it just syncs everything in a single folder ( including folders contained within it)

Comment: It seems to me that what you want is what OneDrive does already. Once you tell it to sync a particular folder, every new file that shows up in that folder (and new subfolders, and files within those) get sync'd with the cloud. They're all within the folder you told it to sync, after all.

Comment: @Jamie Hanrahan : Unfortunately it does not! It only updates the files that OneDrive already contains. I don't know if some configuration is required because I haven't found any way to do this... That's the point of the question!

Comment: It does here. What version of Windows? And if not 10, are you using the OneDrive integration app, or just accessing it through the web?

Comment: @Jamie Hanrahan It's windows 10 and I use the app. For example, last night I created some new folders and files and I also created some new files inside existing folders. None of them appears on OneDrive... unless of course I copy/paste them to OneDrive...

Comment: Case solved with versioning software (Tortoise). I've created a repository inside this folder and when I right click on it I have the option to commit any changes. Then it presents all changes and I tick on them to confirm they'll be saved.